# Compile same Project with different References in Visual Studio

Tags: reference, project

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and developing a plugin for an application. 
This application has a different API (the DLLs I need to reference) depending on its version. 
The code of my plugin works fine for version 2012 and 2013 of the application but I must use the corresponding version of the APIs.

Can I therefore compile same the project with different References in Visual Studio (and so output to 2 different folders) or is the only way to do so to create a duplicate project and change references?

Hope I've been clear,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
You can use conditional compile symbols in the project definition (or for msbuild) and then again in the .csproj (or similar) file you need to manually edit it and add the respective information.

You can also make distinction based on API changes based on the symbols.

This is modified from production code, so there might be a syntax error, it should look something like:

```
</ItemGroup>
<Choose>
  <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('__NEW_DLL_HANDLING_1__')) And !$(DefineConstants.Contains('__NEW_DLL_HANDLING_2__'))">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="mydll, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>..\Additional\mydll1\mydll.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('__NEW_DLL_HANDLING_1__'))">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="mydll, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>..\\Additional\mydll2\mydll.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
```